# Ошибка или описка

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, является ли ошибкой непостановка мягкого знака в слове *только.* Понятно, что без мягкого знака это слово не произносится, соответственно, и не пишется, мягкий знак слышен. Но возникает вопрос: это описка из-за катастрофического неуспевания записывать за учителем или всё же фонетика?

Answer (score 2):

Это может быть то или другое, в зависимости от степени владения языком. В случае, если язык изучается *как иностранный* и сначала усвоен на разговорном уровне в фонетически несовершенной форме, ошибка в написании может быть связана и с тем, что человек именно "так слышит" и/или произносит это слово (с твёрдым "л") и ещё не привык видеть его написанным. Даже если фонетические несовершенства были на более ранней стадии изучения языка, нельзя исключить ошибку "по старой памяти".